# tomcat 6 not looking for classes in webapps folder at startup

Tags: classpath, localhost, tomcat6, logging, classnotfoundexception

I have problem where when I start tomcat it logs ClassNotFoundException exceptions in the localhost.log file. I run it under Windows 7. Everything works.

The only way I was able to stop getting the CNFE exceptions was moving all my `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib` content over to `$CATALINA_HOME/lib`
I just don't know where to look for classpath config.

#### How should I configure Tomcat to look for classes in `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib` and `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes` folders?

#### And is there any way of doing this without war file deployement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are deploying the project as .war then you should not get the ClassNotFoundException but i suggest you to rework on your project set up.

If you are using the Eclipse IDE then just setup a new server in the IDE and then Run As>Run In Server....this may help i.e. redefining your server and redeploying too .

Comment: I am not friendly with IntelliJ but I hope that the setting up your project environment carefully again will surely help you.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound obvious, but did you try deploying it as a war file instead? (If this a java project)